# Dojo InlineTextBox without autosave but save on enter

Tags: dojo, inline-editing

How can I have a dojo InlineTextBox that has autoSave="false" but saves changed text if the user hits the enter key?
Is it possible to have the 'save' and 'cancel' buttons and the save on enter behavior of autoSave='true'?

Comment: I found a solution using the dojo class mechanism. Overriding dijit.InlineEditBox and dijit._InlineEditor did the job. dijit._InlineEditor has the _onKeyPress-Handler and dijit.InlineEditBox had to be changed to use the new inline editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, there's no good way to do that now.

Of course you could edit the source code; this.autoSave is referenced in two places and it should be clear which one is for the enter key behavior... but that's a janky solution.